# Change or rewrite reported root directory

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, mamp

I have a production server running WHM/cPanel. I develop my Wordpress sites locally on my Mac using MAMP.  I use the 'hosts' file to point my URL's to localhost so I don't have to change the URL in my local dev database, which helps in migrating back and forth.

The thing that still differs and often causes issues is the server path.

On production the server path is:

```
/home/cvc1968/public_html
```

While on my local MAMP install (which I keep on Dropbox so I can work from home or office) it is:

```
/Dropbox/MAMP/htdocs/cvc1968/public_html
```

Some plugins use the server path and store it in the database, so when I export/import I often end up with php errors 'file does not exist', etc.

I have figured out how to retake the '/home' folder on the Mac and have attempted to place symlink of the 'cvc1968' folder there, and configured the VirtualHost DocumentRoot in the httpd-vhosts.conf file to '/home/cvc1968/public_html/'.  The site still reports the Dropbox location as the server directory (using the php command getcwd() ), regardless of whether I include the FollowSimLinks option or not.

My Question is:  Is there any way, perhaps using the apache config files in MAMP, or any other method, to keep my files where they are, but have the local site report that its directory path is the same as the production path?

Comment: Why not just set the right `DocumentRoot` in your apache configuration?

Comment: I'm not being clear.  I do have the `DocumentRoot` set up correctly in each configuration, as Ortomala suggested below. I have several plugins that store paths to folders (i.e. iThemes Security stores the server path to both its backup directory and its logs directory.)  This means that when I migrate the database from MAMP to Production or vice versa, I have to do a search/replace in the SQL file to change that server path.  I'm hoping that there is a way to keep the local files where I want them, but 'trick' those plugins into thinking the server path is the same as Production's.

Comment: This depends on each plugin configuration. If you use only paths relative to the DocumentRoot path, it should be ok. Paths stored in logs and backup should not be a problem because they are not used when serving requests.

Comment: I have no control over the plugins' behavior without modifying the plugins code, which would be lost on update. I'm beginning to get the sense that the only solution is for me to re-take my Mac's /home folder, place all my site files there, then symlink to that from the Dropbox directory.  I've confirmed that Dropbox follows the symlink and uploads all the files.  My big worry is what happens to my /home folder next time I upgrade MacOS. I'll have to create a synchronized backup of all the sites I put there.

Comment: Also, FYI, when the path is wrong, it throws php errors on my homepage, but also prevents cookies from being set and I can't login to the site.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use the [`DocumentRoot`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#documentroot) directive.

In your production server apache configuration add :

```
DocumentRoot /home/cvc1968/public_html
```

and in your mac apache configuration add :

```
DocumentRoot /Dropbox/MAMP/htdocs/cvc1968/public_html
```

Depending on your actual configuration and on if plugins have already stored wrong paths in the database, you maybe need to do a clean reinstall.